# Question on finite fields and their extensions

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I have been given this question in Algebra class on finite fields which I have tried to solve but to no avail, so all help appreciated.
I am given $ p=13;q=p^6 $, then I am asked to prove or give a counterexample to the following claim:
There exists $ \alpha \in F_q $ such that $ F_q = F_p[\alpha] $ and also $ \alpha^6 \in F_p $
I have no idea if it is true or not and really have no intuition, even after trying, as to how to approach this problem.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha^6  = c\in \mathbb F_{13}$, then $\alpha$ is a root of $x^6-c$. Can a polynomial of the form $x^6-a$, $a \in \mathbb F_{13}$ be an _irreducible_ polynomial? Obviously not if $a$ has a square root in $\mathbb F_{13}$. So, what if $a$ does not have a square root? If $x^6-a$ is irreducible for at least one value of $a$, you are done since you have proved existence. If $x^6-a$ is reducible for all $a$, then you have proved nonexistence of an $\alpha$ with the stated properties.

Comment: Excuse me @DilipSarwate but could you please help me to determine if $   x^6-a $ is irreducible or reducible modulo 13 Could you please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan of attack:

1. Some elements of $\Bbb{F}_{13}$ are roots of unity of order twelve. Find at least one.
2. If $c$ is a root of unity of order $12$, and $\alpha^6=c$, then show that $\alpha$ is a root of unity of order $72$. Careful! It does **not** always hold that if $c$ is of order $n$ and $\alpha^m=c$ that $\alpha$ would be of order $mn$. But this is a special case! Why?
3. The smallest extension field of $\Bbb{F}_{13}$ that contains roots of unity of order $72$ is $\Bbb{F}_{13^m}$, where ... why don't you determine $m$!
4. Depending on the value of $m$ in step 3 you can then answer the question.

Edit: Remember that an irreducible factor of degree $k$ of $x^6-c$ has a root in $\Bbb{F}_{13^k}$.

Comment: Not sure whether this plan is easier to complete than what Dilip suggested under the OP. Part three relies on the student knowing how to take advantage of the cyclicity of the multiplicative group.

Comment: I am confused I know that m we spoke of must be 6 as the smallest extension but how do I explain further? Why is this the answer?

Comment: @zbigniew2015: Review what you know about orders of elements in a cyclic group. For example, if $m$ were equal to two, then $\alpha$ should be in $\Bbb{F}_{169}$. Is it possible that there is a root of unity of order $72$ in $\Bbb{F}_{169}$?

Comment: I tested it and the minimal m must be 6 but this means the smallest extension in which a root for a special polynomial $x^6-c$ where c is a 12th root o unity modulo 13. This I know. But does this show that the polynomial is irreducible? as it is of degree 6 it is insufficient, as far as I was taught, to show it has no root

Comment: Progress! Well done, @zbigniew2015. It is true that a polynomial not having a zero in a field does not imply that the polynomial is irreducible. Think about it as follows. If $p(x)=x^6-c$ (for that chosen $c$) had a irreducible quadratic factor, then that would mean that it has a zero in $\Bbb{F}_{13^2}$ (all irreducible quadratics have a zero in some quadratic extension, but there is only one such extension). If it had a cubic irreducible factor, then it would have a zero in $\Bbb{F}_{13^3}$...

Comment: Finally got it thank you kindly @JyrkiLahtonen